# specifying a SQLAlchemy join using a relationship when there isn't exactly one FK between tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm going through the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial and I'm a bit confused in the "Querying with Joins" section (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).

The schema the tutorial has previously set up is a simple two-table arrangement where `Address.user_id` is a foreign key to `User.id`. In the Address object it is set up as `user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))`.

The basic join syntax does make sense to me:

```
session.query(User).join(Address).filter(Address.email_address=='jack@google.com').all()
```

However, the tutorial then makes the statement: *If there were no foreign keys, or several, Query.join() works better when one of the following forms are used:*

```
query.join(Address, User.id==Address.user_id)    # explicit condition
query.join(User.addresses)                       # specify relationship from left to right
query.join(Address, User.addresses)              # same, with explicit target
query.join('addresses')                          # same, using a string
```

The first example makes sense: If there were no foreign key, or multiple, then we would need to help SQLAlchemy by explicitly specifying the join condition since it couldn't determine from our foreign keys which one to use to perform the join.

However, the last three examples don't really make sense to me. I believe `User.addresses` is the `relationship` that we previously set up on our User object as `relationship("Address", order_by=Address.id, back_populates="user")`, and it has a counterpart on the Address object `user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")`. But in the case where there are no foreign keys, or multiple, I don't see how specifying a specific relationship declaration would really help us.

At least so far in this tutorial, the relationship declarations don't themselves specify a particular foreign key or column relationship to be used to implement the relationship. So far, I think it's just been implicit that we wanted the relationship to use the single foreign key that we did set. So are there other cases where more information is encoded in the relationship object, i.e. some sort of join condition? That's the only way I can see that specifying a `relationship` would provide enough information to specify a join condition if there are zero or more than one foreign keys between two tables.

Comment: "So are there other cases where more information is encoded in the relationship object, i.e. some sort of join condition?" Your intuition is spot on: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html